# Woman discovers her neighbour/housemate is a dragon?

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I'm looking for a story where a woman discovers that her neighbour/housemate/landlord is a dragon.  I think they share a (possibly old?) house, but maybe it's an apartment-building.  I think main-character knows about supernaturals -- possibly is something supernatural (vampire, reaper, psycic) or has connections with supernaturals.

Anyway, at one point our heroine discovers a dragon in the house, and naturally attacks it.  They fight for a while, before the dragon morphs into that of the woman she shares the house with.

Comment: Googling "roommate is a dragon" returned one hit; http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18136617-cast-in-flame

Comment: What was the setting, Urban fantasy, Sword&sorcery? When did you read it? What do you recall about the dragon (shape, size, etc)? What do you recall about the characters (names, ages, ethnicity)?

Answer (score 3):

A novel that immediately came to mind was *Tea with the Black Dragon* by R.A. MacAvoy. From Wikipedia:Tea with the Black Dragon is about Martha MacNamara, called west to San Francisco by a message from her daughter, Elizabeth, a computer programmer. When she arrives, however, Elizabeth has disappeared. Mayland Long, an Asian gentleman, who is skilled in languages, including those used for computer programming (he settles down to read Donald Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming with a “contented sigh”) and who may be a transformed 2,000 year old Chinese dragon, aids Martha in her search for her daughter. As they search for clues to Elizabeth's disappearance, they discover hints that Elizabeth is involved in a dangerous crime.